# Styling Birt reports

Tags: html, css, birt

I have some problem with text and image alignment(they should be on the same height).I tried to apply some css styles like "vertical-align: middle;" but it doesn't seem to work in pdf specified output format. Inside Grid item I use text item and got the output:
[image]
The part of text item (one checkbox):

```
 <div style="background-color:GRAY"><span> 
Permanent </span><IMG src="<VALUE-OF>occur[0]</VALUE-OF>" height="0.3cm" width="0.3cm"><span> </span></div>
```

The second issue (different component of the report) is to get rid of white space shown in the picture below in yellow:

[image]
The report layout consists of grid item and label items inside.I set height property of Grid and Row to empty value. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the "outline" view to select your Grid-Cell. If you click on it in Desing-View you will probably only click on the label inside your Grid-Cell.

Select the "Padding" Register in the Property Editor and change all values to 0 (default is 1). Repeat this step also for your Labels. This should remove the white space.

Perhaps you can use the Padding to shift your Images and Text onto the same line if you add them in different components and not in a single div.

[image: Padding of items]